# Adding published date to a post in php

Tags: php, date

I'm new to php and I'm trying to display the date added to projects, basically when you submit a project it should visualise the date added, but I have no idea how to do it. Any help?

I tried using         `echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i A");`
It shows the date but keeps increasing.

```
    <?
    while ($row_project = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_projects)){
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row_project['title']." ";

    echo "<img src='";
    echo $row_project['image'];
    echo "' width='200px' /> ";

    echo $row_project['description']." ";
    echo $row_project['projects_uniqueid']." ";
    echo "<br>";

    echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i A");

    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: `date()` will return the current date always. You must store the date when you add the project, by adding a datetime column to your table.

Answer (score 0):

mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)

```
<?php
$d=mktime(11, 14, 54, 8, 12, 2014);
echo "Created date is " . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);
?>
```